# Countif with selection to the last non-empty cell in a column

Tags: vba, formula

My rng1 only contains non-empty cells to the last cell in column A. I want to count cells greater than the value in B1 in rng1. However, this formula didn't work and showed error was due to empty cells.

```
Sub CountRng1()
Dim rng1 As Range
Set rng1 = Range(Range("A2"), Range("A2").End(xlDown))
Range("C1").formula="=countif(rng1,"">""&B1)"
End Sub
```

[image: excel table]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `xlDown` highly unreliable. Use this one instead:

```
Sub CountRng1()
    Dim lastrow As Long
    Dim rng1 As Range

    lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = Range("A2:A" & lastrow)
    Range("C1").Formula = "=COUNTIF(" & rng1.Address & ","">"" & B1)"
End Sub
```

Read this please: [How to determine last used row/column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-finding-last-used-cell-in-vba/11169920#11169920)

Also I suggets you to fully qualify your ranges, i.e. change `Range("A1")` to `ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("sheetName").Range("A1")`

Comment: When I am saving all macros in my Personal Macro WorkBook, I guess it's not necessarily to fully qualify the ranges, am I right?

Comment: I would say it makes it more necessary, but instead of `ThisWorkbook` use `ActiveWorkbook` and instead of specifying a sheet, use `ActiveSheet`

Comment: @AmandaS, you're right, if you're going to use this macro always in _active wroksheet_, just leave it as it is now, `Set rng1 = Range("A2:A" & lastrow)`